# Is there any evidence that Google prioritizes indexing for more urgent topics?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing

I'm curious to know if there's any evidence or comments from Google indicating they prioritize page indexing based on urgency of the topic?  For instance, there's lot's of COVID-19 information that is obviously urgent.  Is there any indication that Google would give priority to indexing these pages over non virus related pages?

If not, are we to assume the primary priority would be based on Google's own domain quality ranking and frequency of published content?

**Clarification:**  I'm not asking about ranking per se, but about Google prioritizing which pages it indexes first.  With several million new pages per day, is there a priority queue for certain content?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's my experience, though not scientific.  I don't have a site that has Expertise, Authority or Trust as it relates to the medical field, so I have no E.A.T. credibility as it relates to the current pandemic.

I wrote a blog post relating the virus to my industry.  Nothing serious, more of a humorous story about the lengths some people are going to during the pandemic.  Definitely nothing that I would want to preempt serious medical content.

Most of the content I normally write, takes about a week before it starts getting organic hits.  GSC also typically takes 7-10 days before it shows an increase in the number valid pages (under Coverage), which I've always interpreted to mean "Google has finally indexed my page".

The blog post I wrote started showing up in Google Analytics within a few hours, but GSC still hadn't shown an increase in the valid page count.  When I used GSC to evaluate what queries users were using that Google displayed my page for, the queries were a broad mix but related to what Google thought were keywords in my blog post.

I'll keep this updated as time progresses and if I see anything different.

**April 4 update.**  I've posted 3 or 4 blog posts around current issue with COVID-19 and CARES Act.  Each of them has been picked up by Google within 24 hours.  I.e., users coming from Google. I know that doesn't prove that Google places a priority for urgency, but it's obviously aware of current trends and news.

Answer (score 0):

E.A.T. is going to be the most important factor in COVID-related content. If you're not a research institution or an established medical journal or top news provider, you're going to have a much harder time ranking. (Which, sorry, is a good thing).

For content categorized as news, recency is a ranking factor.

"Urgency" is not.

Comment: E.A.T is not a ranking factor [says Google](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-systems-arent-looking-for-eat-29031.html), but Google hopes that its ranking factors align with E.A.T.